# CSS select SVG within content of the :pseudo-element

Tags: css, svg, pseudo-element

```
div:before
{
    content: url(path_to_my_svg);
}
```

Is there a way to select the SVG which is inside the content of the :pseudo-element?
like:

```
div:before svg
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is here. The obvious answer is no, but perhaps if you explain the problem there's another approach we could suggest.

Comment: ``url(...)`` are considered external images, so CSS selectors will not work. You can use the ``<load-file>`` Web Component I wrote, to load an external SVG - inline it - and apply CSS: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd